# Flutter SDK is incomplete during setting up Path in Android Studio Ubuntu 20.04 Flutter project creation

Tags: android-studio, flutter, ubuntu-20.04

Hi have downloaded new version of Android Studio 4.1.1.
Installed Flutter and Dart plugin and also downloaded Flutter installation and unzipped into my specific location, but during the option to choose Flutter Path in Android studio, while I am creating Flutter project alwais get error:

> the flutter sdk installation is incomplete please see https //flutter.dev/get-started
> any same experience?

Comment: I think you didn't finish installing the flutter sdk. Try installing it again and don't forget to add flutter to path in ~/.bashrc . Follow the instructions here: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux . You can choose to automatically install flutter through snap(d) but it is slower than manually installing it.

Comment: It works by command Line but throught Android Studio nope.. when you create from Android Studio a project it ask for Flutter path and no way to recognize it, if you create Project via CLI it works.

Comment: You've configured android studio incorrectly. Why not try using vscode? It is much lighter and faster. You could get debugging info and performance benchmarks through flutter profiler

Answer (score -1):

I think you downloaded the latest version which is not complete and you should download a version before the final version